# Multi-referencing with cleveref: is \cpageref compression bugged, or am I using it wrong?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I am running into problems using `\cpageref` in `cleveref`. It seems like if it tries to "compress" pages as part of a 3+ input `\cpageref`, something goes horribly wrong and it just prints the *labels* of the first and last inputs. I'm not sure if I have a gross misunderstanding of how `\cpageref` is supposed to work, or if there's some kind of bug.

Here's a minimal example of what is going on:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Holy Grail \label{hg-1}} \par
\textbf{Life of Brian \label{lob-1}}\par

\newpage
\textbf{This page only references the Holy Grail \label{hg-2}} \par

\newpage
\textbf{This page again references both the Holy Grail \label{hg-3} and the Life of Brian \label{lob-2}} \par

\newpage
\textbf{References} \par
Monty Python and the Holy Grail \ldots{} \cpageref{hg-1,hg-2,hg-3} \par
The Life of Brian \ldots{} \cpageref{lob-1,lob-2} \par

\end{document}
```

The expectation: the final page would read:

> **References**
> Monty Python and the Holy Grail ... pages 1 to 3
> The Life of Brian ... pages 1 and 3

What actually happens:

> **References**
> Monty Python and the Holy Grail ... hg-1hg-3
> The Life of Brian ... pages 1 and 3

I am fairly certain this is a problem with `cleveref`'s consecutive reference compression, because If I disable it (`\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}`), I get this instead:

> **References**
> Monty Python and the Holy Grail ... pages 1, 2 and 3
> The Life of Brian ... pages 1 and 3

Is there a workaround or proper way to get the `pages 1 to 3` output? Or is this a limitation or bug in `cleveref`?

**Latex engine:** `MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.6 (MiKTeX 21.3 Portable)`

**cleveref version:**

```
\def\packagedate{2018/03/27}
\def\packageversion{0.21.4}
```

*Update:* Checked with the latest "pre-release" version (0.21.5) and the behavior is the same.

Version 0.19.1 from [Tony Cubitt's site](https://www.dr-qubit.org/cleveref.html) seems to not have this problem.

Comment: It looks like this question might have been asked before, with no success: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496998/242024

Comment: I reported that bug  last year but got no answer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did you receive any answer since you commented? I am also meeting this issue (better described, as far as it appears to me, at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496998/105447). I'll probably write him too since it is pretty bad (no compilation warning, no log info, just square wrong output...).

Comment: @gusbrs no, I didn't year anything.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for answering. I have written to Toby too, at least he is thus able to assess affected users. Let's hope he eventually gets to it, since this really lets the package in a tight spot... If the thing is two years old (as the other question shows), having to control for this kind of silent failure makes me weary in using it at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've been digging `cleveref.sty`, and I think I found the problem and a possible fix. But I'm not sure of it, since my TeX-fu is not really marvelous. Would you care to discuss it? If so, where through?

Comment: @gusbrs I'm not much using cleveref. I would suggest that you ask a question showing the bug and your fix and ask if it looks right.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, thanks! I'll do it soon.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Done! At https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603514/105447 .