# Cross Referencing Multiple Pages with the Pageref and Label Commands

Tags: cross-referencing

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}
\itemsep3.0em
\item Item 1

Please see pp. \pageref{R1}

\newpage
\item Item 4 \label{R1}
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7

\newpage
\item Item 8 \label{R1}
\item Item 9
\item Item 10

\newpage
\item Item 11 \label{R1}
\item Item 12
\item Item 13 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

However, in the code, I've referenced *three* consecutive pages; specifically, pages 2, 3, and 4.

QUESTION: How may I obtain something like *Please see pp. 2--4*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to reference three different labels you have to use three different label names.

You can use `cleveref` to automatic convert page references to ranges. [But due to a bug, you also need a patch](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603514/277964):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@setcpagerefrange}[3]{%
  \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{cref}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\@setCpagerefrange}[3]{%
  \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{Cref}{#3}}
\newcommand*{\@setlabelcpagerefrange}[3]{%
  \@@setcpagerefrange{#1}{#2}{labelcref}{#3}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{enumerate}
\itemsep3.0em
\item Item 1

Please see \cpageref{R1,R2,R3}.

\newpage
\item Item 4 \label{R1}
\item Item 5
\item Item 6
\item Item 7

\newpage
\item Item 8 \label{R2}
\item Item 9
\item Item 10

\newpage
\item Item 11 \label{R3}
\item Item 12
\item Item 13 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Please see pages 2 to 4]

To get instead `pp. 2–4` you can add

```
\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\newcommand*{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

to the document preamble. But note, the definition of `\crefrangeconjunction` will also change the output of other ranges, e.g., of `\cref{R1,R2,R3}`.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.