# An Efficient Way to Cross Reference a Large Number of Consecutive Pages

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

This is a follow-up to [Cross Referencing Multiple Pages with the Pageref and Label Commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/687513/cross-referencing-multiple-pages-with-the-pageref-and-label-commands)

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref}

% To print a dash between the page numbers in the range.
\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\newcommand*{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

See \cpageref{R1,R2,R3,R4}.

\newpage
Some words.
\label{R1}
\newpage
Some words.
\label{R2}
\newpage
Some words.
\label{R3}
\newpage
Some words.
\label{R4}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Though the output is exactly what I want, it seems that the labeling task might become quite laborious if, say, a hundred consecutive cross-referenced pages were involved.

QUESTION: How may I make the labeling process more efficient; that is, might there be a way, say, to reference the first and last pages in a consecutive string of pages so that LateX produces the desired output, in this case, *See pp. 2--5* without having to label *every* referenced page?

Thank you.

Comment: @Teepeemm No; it's not clear to me how such is to be incorporated; does such obviate the need for reference labels; if so how? Perhaps you might post a working answer that clearly shows the application of these commands that you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> might there be a way, say, to reference the first and last pages in a consecutive string of pages so that LateX produces the desired output, in this case, "See pp. 2--5" without having to label *every* referenced page?

`cleveref` defines `\cpagerefrange`, so that

```
See \cpagerefrange{R1}{R4}.
```

gives the output you want.

(Note also that your original example needs the patch from the linked answer in order to have the output you show.  `\cpagerefrange` doesn't need the patch.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the above answer but got a little confused at first. When I figured it out, I thought it might be helpful to post a full working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cleveref} %defines \cpagerefrange

% Print a dash between the page numbers in the range:
\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\newcommand*{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

See \cpagerefrange{R1}{R4}

\newpage
Some words.
\label{R1}

\newpage
Some words.

\newpage
Some words.

\newpage
Some words.
\label{R4}
\end{document}
```

Giving the desired output:

[image]